# Google maps query limit exceeded. When i can use the service again?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I know that the limit is 2500 queries per day, but is the count reset at 00:00 (midnight) of the new day or 24 after that you hit the limit?

Comment: I do not know.. but it could also be a last 24 hours count.. so it releases uses as the time passes..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This seems to suggest it is 24 hours from the time you hit the limit:

> If you exceed the 24-hour limit

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/#Limits

Answer (score 2):

It suggests 24 hours.

May I suggest if you are hitting the limit you consider client side geocoding using the JavaScript API (if you are serving a web page of course); this will mean the quota comes out of the client IP address allowance rather than the allowance for the IP your server has.

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/services.html#Geocoding

If you need to obtain lat/long and post them in to a database, you could still use the client side API and just populate some form fields with lat/lng.